# insert error code 1241 operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I am trying to Insert data  into zone_sig

```
INSERT INTO zone_sig values (0,0,0,0,'24','Siliana','Kesra','2459',(0.95830721023,0.03643552658),'Région du Nord-Ouest',0);
```

but i get the error:

> error code 1241. operand should contain 1 column(s)

Table schema:

```
zone_sig (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADM_IDE int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    SURFACE double DEFAULT NULL,
    PERIMETRE double DEFAULT NULL,
    ADM_COD varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ADM_GOV varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ADM_DEL varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    CODE_INS varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ogc_geom geometry DEFAULT NULL,
    NOM_ZONE varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    NIVEAU int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=269 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Too bad you're not trying to find out on your own why this is happening. There's only 500 million results on google about it.

Comment: What does the schema of `zone_sig` look like?  What is `(0.95830721023,0.03643552658)` supposed to represent?

Comment: zone_sig (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADM_IDE int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  SURFACE double DEFAULT NULL,
  PERIMETRE double DEFAULT NULL,
  ADM_COD varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ADM_GOV varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ADM_DEL varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  CODE_INS varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ogc_geom geometry DEFAULT NULL,
  NOM_ZONE varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  NIVEAU int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=269 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Answer (score 1):

When setting a `geometry` field, you can't use `(0.95830721023,0.03643552658)` directly in the query.  MySQL doesn't understand how to use that.

You need to use the `Point` function here.

```
INSERT INTO zone_sig values (0,0,0,0,'24','Siliana','Kesra','2459',Point(0.95830721023,0.03643552658),'Région du Nord-Ouest',0);
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7128c8/1

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-values.html (see section 12.17.4.2.3)